# Can someone help explain how this code works in Roblox?

Tags: plugins, lua, roblox

I have a question about [this](https://www.roblox.com/library/188954291/Model-to-Script-converter-v4-Open-Source) Roblox Plugin. It converts a model to a script. My question here is how does it convert scripts as well? If I had a model with a script, it would run the script as if it was in the model where I put it. We all know that 'scriptModel.Source' is only available for plugins and if it converts it to a script, that script isn't a plugin script. Just a normal script. From what I can tell, this function is what does it:

```lua
function sandbox(var,func)
    local env = getfenv(func)
    local newenv = setmetatable({},{
        __index = function(self,k)
            if k=="script" then
                return var
            else
                return env[k]
            end
        end,
    })
    setfenv(func,newenv)
    return func
end
```

It seems like it has to do with environments. Could someone help me understand this a bit more? I'd like to understand how this works and works so well.

All I understand is, 'var' is a script instance (Instance.new). Then it gets the function's environment/scope. When 'script' is indexed it returns that 'var', otherwise it returns the function environment variables. Did I get something wrong?

Thanks! :D

Answer (score 3):

This function will replace `func`'s environment with one that relays any non-assignment indexing with `"script"` to `var`.

This is similar to `getfenv(func).script = var` with the only difference that you do not modify the original environment.

Comment: Why not just use `getfenv(func).script = var`? Would that not be much easier?

Comment: Like here: https://devforum.roblox.com/t/script-sandboxing-with-behaviour-detection/283678/3

Comment: @Battledash2 I don't know, I have not written that code. the only difference is that you don't change the original environment. that would for example allow you to have different scripts for different functions which share a common environment.

Comment: imagine you have two functions in the same environment. you can do `sandbox(var1, func1)` and `sandbox(var2, func2)`. and `getfenv(func1).test = "hello!"`. now `getfenv(func1).script` is `var1`, `getfenv(func2).script` is `var2`, `getfenv(func1).test` is `"hello!"` and `getfenv(func2).test` is `"hello!"`, because their environments redirect anything but `script` to the original environment.  I'm not sure about the actual use cases as I'm no Roblox expert

Comment: actually you need to assign that "hello!" befor you sandbox the functions. I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

var: A script or a model

func: I don't know

First, it gets the environment of `func`. Then, a new environment is created with this property:

- If the index place is empty, `__index` is triggered. Then if the index name is `script`, it returns the script. Else, it returns the index place of `k` in the environment of the function.

`func`'s environment is then set as the new environment, then it is returned.

Comment: About `return env[k]`, why not just `return env`? Also, what arguments does __index receive? self, and then what's indexed, but what's indexed can be something like `script.Parent` so how is it 'script' and not 'script.Parent'? Or is the 3rd arg (if there even is one) 'Parent' and so on?